# How does MySQL deal with Multiple-Statement? Execute concurrently in backend?

Tags: mysql, database

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/multi-statement.html
Isn't mention in this manual. Thanks for help!

Comment: Why do you care so much about concurrency?  My question here would be whether those multiple statements get executed within a single transaction.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to speed up queries by using Multiple-Statement. If MySQL executes concurrently, it will cost less time besides saving round-trip time.

Comment: I seem to recall that multi statement is generally frowned upon and not used very often.  It may have to do with that it becomes difficult to roll things back if, say, one of ten statements fail.  What would your app do in that case?  Run everything again?  Or try to guess where it should pick up where it left off?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The problem you talk about is difficult to handle. But my current scene is relatively simple, there are only SELECT queries and no  UPDATE/DELETE statements, so I dont need to care about transaction and it would be ideal if MySQL executes concurrently.